# Unable to modify column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement wherein I need to change the table structure as per the production environment on a lower environment. The table has a multi-column **PRIMARY KEY as  (`md_biobjectid`,`projectid`,`md_mapid`)**, I want to modify column **'md_mapid' to varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL** from **'md_mapid' varchar(50) NOT NULL**.

When I am running the query :
***alter table table_name
modify column `md_mapid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL;*** it doesn't run and I am getting following error :
Error Code: 1171. All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead.

Other columns structure on both the environment is : 
'md_biobjectid' varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''

'projectid' varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''

MySQL version : 5.7.21-log.

Comment: Its stating exact reason. You can make a primary key using a single column. and these three columns you can make as `Unique`

Comment: because what you're try to do is violating the rule for each primary key constraints.

Comment: can you tell us why you need a null value in a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

you need to isse without `DEFAULT NULL` postfix. md_mapid column is part of composite primary key and cannot be set to null.

```
alter table table_name modify column md_mapid varchar(50)
```